# Android Xamarin Listview no carga los elementos

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, listview, visual-studio-2017

Sucede que, después de crear un listview de la misma forma que explica en la documentación, los elementos no se cargan, como si no hubiese elementos a mostrar.

He comprobado que si, hay elementos en el array de objetos, por lo que en teoría deberían mostrarse.

Código del BaseAdapter:

```
public class SelectorScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<Campeonato>
{
    Campeonato[] campeonatos;
    Activity context;

    public SelectorScreenAdapter(Activity ctx, Campeonato[] items) : base()
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.campeonatos = items;
    }

    public override Campeonato this[int position] {
        get
        {
            return campeonatos[position];
        }
    }

    public override int Count {
        get
        {
            return campeonatos.Count();
        }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        if(campeonatos.Count() > position)
        {
            return (long)campeonatos[position].ID1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        Campeonato item = campeonatos[position];
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customRow, null, false);
        }
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nombreCamp).Text = item.C_nombre;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.zonaCamp).Text = item.Zona;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.localidadCamp).Text = item.Localidad;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.fechaCamp).Text = item.Ic_ano.ToString();
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.categoriaCamp).Text = item.Tipo;
        return view;
    }
}
```

Código de la introduccion de objetos en la lista y el evento pertinente:

```
public void loadItems(int userINT)
    {
        logMessage("Loading Items...");
        listView = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.list);


        SelectorScreenAdapter selectorScreenAdapter;
        model.DatabaseRetrieveCampeonatos(userINT);

        selectorScreenAdapter = new SelectorScreenAdapter(this, model.getArrayCampeonatos());
        listView.Adapter = selectorScreenAdapter;
        logMessage("Items Loaded");
        listView.ItemClick += gotoCampeonato;
        logMessage("Event Added");
        listView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
    }
```

Código del OnCreate:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.selector_campeonatos);
        this.model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(Intent.GetStringExtra("MODEL"));

        loadItems(model.getLogin().GetLicencia());
    }
```

Y los Layout:

selector_campeonatos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

customRow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFDAFF7F"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombreCamp"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Text1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fechaCamp"
                android:text="Fecha"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textColor="#FF267F00"
                android:paddingLeft="100dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/localidadCamp"
                android:text="Localidad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textColor="#FF267F00"
                android:paddingLeft="95dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Text2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zonaCamp"
                android:text="Zona"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textColor="#FF267F00"
                android:paddingLeft="100dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categoriaCamp"
                android:text="Categoria"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textColor="#FF267F00"
                android:paddingLeft="100dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: En el inflate estas enviando null. Intenta enviando el `parent` asi :             `view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.customRow, parent, false);` y me dices que pasa.

Comment: puedes poner el método : DatabaseRetrieveCampeonatos